# WordPress Archives Cause Looping

Tags: permalinks, archives, archive-template, wp-get-archives

I am attempting to create an archives page that would have links to authors, categories, tags, etc. I would like it so that when the author, for example, is clicked, all their posts are displayed. Currently, if you go to http://diginomics.com/archive/ you see that clicking the link only brings you back to the archive page, essentially creating a loop.

This is my current code for the archive page template archive.php:

```
    <?php the_post(); ?>

    <h3>Posts by author:</h3>

    <?php $args = array(
        'orderby'       => 'name', 
        'order'         => 'ASC', 
        'number'        => null,
        'optioncount'   => false, 
        'exclude_admin' => true, 
        'show_fullname' => false,
        'hide_empty'    => true,
        'echo'          => true,
        'style'         => 'list',
        'html'          => true ); ?>

    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_authors( $args ); ?>
    </ul>

    <h3>Archive by month:</h3>

    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h3>Archive by category:</h3>

    <ul>
         <?php wp_list_categories( 'title_li=' ); ?>
    </ul>

    <h3>All posts alphabetically:</h3>

    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=alpha'); ?>
    </ul>

    <h3>Tag cloud:</h3>

    <ul>
        <?php wp_tag_cloud(); ?>
    </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change to get the desired effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't name your custom page template `archive.php`. If you refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you'll see that `archive.php` is the template WordPress loads for archives if a more specific template isn't available.

Comment: Followed this advice which seemed to work well enough, but now when I click on a specific author to look up, I get some random post before the results. Check it out and you will see what I mean. Code remains the same.

Comment: I can't explain that without seeing your templates. Look at the template hierarchy, figure out what template your author archives is loading, and look at the code for that particular template.